# Тире в предложении "Что значит — родина!"

Tags: пунктуация

*— Что значит — родина! — удовлетворенно вздохнул Пантелей Прокофьевич.*
[**М. Шолохов. Тихий Дон**](https://aphorisms.su/knigi/romani/tihij_don/kniga_2_chastj_5/glava_13.html)

Почему между "значит" и "Родина" ставится тире? Оно нужно в данном случае для того, чтобы сделать акцент на слове "Родина"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *— Что значит — родина! — удовлетворенно вздохнул Пантелей Прокофьевич.*
>
> Почему между "значит" и "Родина" ставится тире? Оно нужно в данном
>   случае **для того, чтобы сделать акцент на слове "Родина"?**

Именно так. Авторское тире, помогающее при прочтении обозначить паузу и сделать акцент на слове "Родина".

В подобных предложениях тире может и отсутствовать, но тогда предложение будет звучать примерно так:

> *— Что значит молодость! — произнёс спокойно Базаров* (Тургенев. Отцы и дети).